# std::conditional is not evaluated

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

Consider the following:

```
template <bool flag> std::conditional<flag, int, double> f() { return 0; }

void g(int a);

int main() {
    g(f<true>());
    return 0;
}
```

gcc 4.8.2 complains:

```
temp.cpp:18:16: error: cannot convert ‘std::conditional<true, int, double>’ to ‘int’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void g(int)’
     g(f<true>());
                ^
temp.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::conditional<flag, int, double> f() [with bool flag = true]’:
temp.cpp:18:15:   required from here
temp.cpp:13:71: error: could not convert ‘0’ from ‘int’ to ‘std::conditional<true, int, double>’
 template <bool flag> std::conditional<flag, int, double> f() { return 0; }
```

It looks like `std::conditional` is not evaluated to `int` as I would expect. Why is this the case and how can this small example be fixed?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be "evaluated to `int`"? Was it something in the documentation?

Comment: `template< bool B, class T, class F > struct conditional;` The documentation says: "Provides member typedef type, which is defined as `T` if `B` is `true` at compile time, or as `F` if `B` is `false`." In our case, `B` is `true` and `T` is `int`.

Comment: But it doesn't say an `std::conditional<bool, int, double>` evaluates to `int`. The clue is in the "member typedef".

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to return an instance of `std::conditional<...>`, not the type which results from the evaluation, which is held in a `type` member type. To retrieve the computed type you could use `std::conditional_t`:

```
template <bool flag> 
std::conditional_t<flag, int, double> 
f() { return 0; }
```

`std::conditional_t` is C++14, so if you're stuck with C++11 you can do this instead:

```
template <bool flag> 
typename std::conditional<flag, int, double>::type 
f() { return 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "iostream"
template <bool flag> typename std::conditional<flag, int, double>::type f() { return 0; }

void g(int a);

int main() {
    g(f<true>());
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/lf52TO